# Ruby gem simple_form 3.1.0 radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button, simple-form

I use simple_form for displaying radio button for boolean attribute

```
<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :is_deleted, as: :radio_buttons %>
<% end %>
```

But instead of 2 radio buttons with yes/no titles i see just titles yes/no and no radio buttons. What's wrong?

EDIT

[image: here is rendered html for my code]

[image: here is rendered html for Max's code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :is_deleted, as: :radio_buttons,  :collection => [[true, 'Yes'], [false, 'No']]  %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously you can substitute whatever values you want to display for "Yes" and "No"

Comment: Problem is i see these titles for radio buttons (yes/no, true/false), but i do not see radiobuttons themselves (these little circles)

Comment: Can you add the rendered HTML (for your original code, and for my code, if the results are different to yours) to your question in an EDIT please?

Comment: I've edited question. First screenshot is for my code, second is for yours

Comment: The html looks fine.  Maybe it's being hidden because of styling?  Use chrome inspector (or your browser's equivalent) to look at one of the radio buttons - looking at the computed styles can sometimes be more helpful than looking down the list of all style rules being applied to the element.  You're probably looking for some style rule that's putting `display:none` on it.

Comment: I've added item_wrapper_class: 'inline' and now everything is ok :) thank u very much

Comment: Cool.  In a situation like this your first thing to do should always be inspect the element and see if the html is correct.  If the html is wrong, then it's a rails template problem.  If the html is ok then it's a styling issue, and you can usually see why that style is being applied to the element in the inspector too.